# Google Script - Using a JS variable in html file

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I want to include a variable that I normally use in a .gs file in my html file. For example, the following code would make variable 'value' be the content of whatever is in cell A1:

```
var value = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A1").getValue();
```

How can I include this variable in my .html file, so that typing 'value' in the html file will return the contents of cell A1?

EDIT

What I'm trying to achieve is build a mail action button that automatically submits a google form, filled with the data in the spreadsheet. The script I have for the .html file is as follows:

```
<div>
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "EmailMessage",
  "action": {
    "@type": "ConfirmAction",
    "name": "Accept",
    "handler": {
      "@type": "HttpActionHandler",
      "url": "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/139j-0POMG9BVqttXnY8l-6YMI7M2DReREIuJJd_waJE/formResponse?ifq&entry.1766440389=" + value + "&entry.1329637906&submit=Submit"
    }
  },
  "description": ""
}

</script>

</div>
```

The button works perfectly fine, but I need to prefill the form by adding the variable in the middle of the url (under 'handler' where I typed " + value + "), containing the contents of the cell. Only problem is that I can't figure out how to integrate that variable in the .html file

Comment: You need to provide more information.  Typing a word into an HTML file will never return anything.  So, that's not possible.  Do you want to type something into an input field, and get information back?  Are you familiar with `google.script.run`?  That's probably where you need to start.  [Google Documentation - google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: Not sure if that is what I'm looking for (sorry, I'm quite new to programming, learning it all as I go along). I've just edited the original post to explain what exactly I'm trying to achieve, if that helps. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You have a text formula:

```
"url": "https://docs.google.com/forms/d/139j-0POMG9BVqttXnY8l-6YMI7M2DReREIuJJd_waJE/formResponse?ifq&entry.1766440389=" + value + "&entry.1329637906&submit=Submit"
```

And you are adding a variable to a URL search string.  You want the value to be looked up from the spreadsheet, and put into the URL.

So, I guess you have a button that starts the process?  When the button is clicked, it should run `google.script.run`.  Then, when the server side `.gs` function is done running, it will return a value, and you will need an `withSuccessHandler(function)` to start the function that will take the returned value, and put it into the URL.

Start with reading the documentation for `google.script.run`.